# Is there a way to generate a static assets folder for a phoenix project?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

For a school project, I generated a phoenix project with the --no-webpack option.
Now we needed to extend our project with javascript and webpack.
The problem is I don't have an assets folder and I'm wondering if there's still a way to generate it or another possible fix.
I already tried generating another project and copy pasting my files between them but this gave me errors in different files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating another project is a way to go, but you could let `git` to do the merge for you.

Generate a project with the same name in other directory and then merge with `allow-unrelated-histories` option:

```sh
git merge ../other-folder/same-project-name --allow-unrelated-histories
```

Then you will need to resolve conflicts on some files, but they are easy to resolve.